# MS Access query count and show

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with cities and publishers in those cities.

How do I create a query that counts how many publishers are in which city, and then also shows the names of those publishers only for the city with the most publishers.

Comment: Show us your table structure/sample data and you'll probably get an answer fairly quickly.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/z3u8k3jbr/

Comment: basically i need a query that would show all of the publishers in alphabetical order but only those, that live in a city with the biggest number of publishers

Comment: Do `Publishers` have their own table?

Comment: Well, what do you want here? A count of publisher in each city, or names of publishers only for the city with the most publishers? They are different

Comment: names of publishers only for the city with the most publishers...but dont you have to count them first in one query and then use that query with another that would show them ? i dont know, but yeah, all i need is the list of publishers but in the city with the most of them

Comment: See my explanation and let me know if it answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
SELECT Sub2.City, 
       Table1.Publisher
FROM (
         SELECT TOP 1 Sub.City, Sub.CountOfPublisher AS MaxOfCountOfPublisher
             FROM (SELECT Table1.City,
                          Count(Table1.Publisher) AS CountOfPublisher
                   FROM Table1
                   GROUP BY Table1.City
                   )  AS Sub
ORDER BY Sub.CountOfPublisher DESC
) AS Sub2
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Sub2.City = Table1.City
```

> Note: Replace `Table1` with your table name.

### Explanation

So, we needed to roll up our aggregation so Access can use the information we provided in our `Count`.

From the inside out:

We need a `Count` of `Publisher`s for each `City`, and we want to `Group By` each `City`. This gives us some numbers we can work with per `City`.

[image]

The next piece, we want to select the TOP 1 record from those results, sorted by the `Count` of `Publishers` `DESC` (descending - highest to lowest). So, sorting by the Count Descending makes the first record the `City` with the highest count of `Publishers`. We then use that in our final step.

[image]

Finally, we wanted the `City` and the `Publishers` for the `City` with the most publishers. Well, thus far we have the City with the most `Publishers`, but we don't have a list of `Publishers`. To get those, we need to join our original Table on `City`.

This basically says, I have the `City` with the **most** `Publishers`, now give me all of the records from our Table where the `City` is equal to the `City` (`INNER JOIN Table1 ON Sub2.City = Table1.City`) we are supplying in our query.

[image]

Comment: thanks i can use that, but i was kinda looking for a step by step tut on how to do it, because something like this will be on my tomorrow's exam and i need to do it on my own, i can't just copy and paste it :/

Comment: much better, thanks a lot :) could you perhaps post a picture(s) of design view of the quary(ies)

Comment: @MilošTimko Why did you unaccept? Did I not answer your question?

Comment: sorry, u said the first one was useless so i unchecked it, but now it's good :)

Comment: but i still dont know how did you make it so that only top 1 record is considered in the second query :/